# Cycles artifacts?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Anybody have an idea why cycles are creating these artefacts (almost looks like the wireframe is poking through) vs eevee?[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's hard to guess what is your object and what artefact you are talking about, maybe share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: The object is a topogprahy I created and the renders are from the landscape. The file is more than a gig so can't really share.  As for the artefacts, see the little squares on the cycles render (top photo)

Comment: are you sure that you don't have overlapping faces? Try a M > Merge by Distance in Edit mode?

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it unfortunately. I would have expected Eevee to have the same issue but it only happens in cycles.

Comment: can you share only this part of your file?

Comment: It almost seems in cycles that there is another mesh, hard to explain, please see the blend file  linked. Put the mesh in edit mode and below the hidden faces there is something else which you can't see in eevee, nor can you select it in cycles. http://tinyurl.com/t2muymu6

Comment: I can't see any link, please copy paste the link

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/t2muymu6  - Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I can't see where are these artefacts, I've tried a render in both Eevee and Cycles and it seems ok... Could you please only share the sample you show?

Comment: Please see the link for how mine looks in render view when I go into edit mode. I've hidden some faces but there is something underneath in cycles but not in eevee. Are you not seeing the same on your side? http://tinyurl.com/5dd4dh4t

Comment: In the last picture you show, could you please highlight the artefacts you're talking about? As I said, I don't see anything, I must miss the problem...

Comment: I think I found what it is going on - when I crank up the resolution way high (I'm trying to render for a large print) and renders, the artefacts get  introduced. Still not sure why though. Also seem to be the case when I use a HDRI and not normal lights.

Comment: OK that's weird   ;)  ..............

Comment: Thanks for all the help though - truly appreciate it.